# Getting values from an object in phoneno and email parameters in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

The code below is working fine and it display record from Monday API.

Here is the outputed JSON record via `JSON.stringify()`

`[ { "id": "3150569213", "name": "Task 1", "column_values": [ { "id": "fullname", "value": null }, { "id": "status", "value": null }, { "id": "email", "value": null }, { "id": "phone_number", "value": null }, { "id": "address", "value": null }, { "id": "product", "value": null }, { "id": "quantity", "value": null }, { "id": "reward", "value": null } ] }, { "id": "3150569636", "name": "Recycle Products Share By ann balling", "column_values": [ { "id": "fullname", "value": "\"ann balling\"" }, { "id": "status", "value": "{\"index\":0}" }, { "id": "email", "value": "{\"text\":\"nancy@gmail.com\",\"email\":\"nancy@gmail.com\",\"changed_at\":\"2022-08-27T12:16:47.728Z\"}" }, { "id": "phone_number", "value": "{\"phone\":\"1234567890\",\"countryShortName\":null}" }, { "id": "address", "value": "{\"lat\":\"Texas,\",\"lng\":\"US\",\"address\":\"unknown\"}" }, { "id": "product", "value": "{\"text\":\"Paper,Bottles,Plastic Cans\"}" }, { "id": "quantity", "value": "\"200\"" }, { "id": "reward", "value": "\"Gift\"" } ] } ]`

The property **i.column_values[0].value** displays record **"Nancy More"** and I remove the double quotes around it using `json.parse()` hence `JSON.parse(i.column_values[0].value)`  and its okay.

Here is my issue. The property **i.column_values[1].value** display record object

```
{"text":"nancy@gmail.com","email":"nancy@gmail.com","changed_at":"2022-08-27T12:16:47.728Z"}
```

How do I get **email** value hence **nancy@gmail.com**.

Here is the code

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import mondaySdk from "monday-sdk-js";
const monday = mondaySdk();
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
      
            loading: false,
            datax: [],

        };      

    }

  componentDidMount() {
monday.api(`query {boards (ids: 34443234) {items(limit: 3 page: 1) {id name column_values {
        id
        value
      } }}}`).then(res => {
  console.log(res);
this.setState({datax: res.data.boards[0].items});
});

  }

    render() {
const {loading } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>


  
   <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Fullname</th>
         <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>
{this.state.datax.map((i, index) => (
     <tr key={index}>
 <td>{JSON.parse(i.column_values[0].value)}</td>
 <td>{i.column_values[1].value}</td>
      </tr>
  ))}



    </tbody>
  </table>



{JSON.stringify(this.state.datax, null, 2)}

            
            <br />



            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please show us the way you process the data right after fetching it. The JSON data is broken.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. This is the line of code which prints the json record. `{JSON.stringify(this.state.datax, null, 2)}`

Comment: What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: When you said `json.strigfy()`, I assume from your main code body that you meant `JSON.stringify()`. It is rather a concern that in supplying a piece of code to readers involving two words, you managed to misspell them both. This is my experience with your entire post history - a lack of effort and a lack of attention to detail. Are you able to improve on this for your future questions?

Comment: @Enfieldli - it looks like the JSON is valid ([confirmed here](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)). However some strings in the structure are themselves JSON, so would need additional decoding.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is how I got the email address value working

```
<td>{i.column_values[2].value.split(':')[1].split('"')[1]}</td>
```

Comment: This might be a brittle solution - it relies on tricks to decode JSON inside a JS object (which itself was decoded from JSON). It would be better for the data not to be stored that way, but if you have no choice, then at least use a proper JSON parser to do the secondary decoding.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. At the moment, that is the only solution that I have.Please help me with a better solution. hope to hear from you . Thanks